# how to find the unique values of two columns in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

To count the unique value of a column and add them to the dataframe I use the following code which works

```
    df["num_query"] = df.groupby([FID])['qid'].transform('nunique')
```

However now I want to count them based on two columns, something like:

```
    df["num_query"] = df.groupby([FID])['qid', 'prefix'].transform('nunique')
```

Ith gives the error:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
```

Comment: I'm guessing you wanted to pass in a list `[['qid','prefix']]`

Comment: @Chris By this change, it gave the same error